# Simple WebView Crashing

Tags: android, eclipse, webview

After clicking button, the app crashes, not sure why..

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button button;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }

        });
```

WebViewActivity:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends MainActivity {

private WebView webView;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");


}



   }
```

webview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/webView1" >   
</WebView>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.webview.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonUrl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
    android:text="Go to website" />
```

I am testing on Android 4.4, and have tried on a Nexus 4 with same result (crash).

I am using this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Logcat Error:

```
06-14 22:01:17.871: D/AndroidRuntime(1049): Shutting down VM
```

06-14 22:01:17.871: W/dalvikvm(1049): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a4eba8)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): Process: com.example.webview, PID: 1049
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.webview/com.example.webview.WebViewActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.example.webview.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 22:01:21.071: I/Process(1049): Sending signal. PID: 1049 SIG: 9

Comment: What error did you get in Logcat?

Comment: Have added the logcat errors

Comment: You need to declare your `WebViewActivity` in your android `Manifest.xml`

Comment: paste you manifest file also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your logcat shows the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): Process: 
com.example.webview, PID: 1049 06-14 22:01:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): 
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class 
{com.example.webview/com.example.webview.WebViewActivity}; have you declared this 
activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

according to this exception,all i can say that:

```
1. you have to declare your webviewActivity in your manifest file.
2_. or the declaration might be wrong.that is why when you fire intent to WebViewActivity,
the system coundn't find the activity in manifest file.i.e why it throws activity not found exception.
```

## solution

```
<activity
    android:name:"your_package_name.WebViewActivity">
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. For some reason when I did that before it didn't solve the issue.